# What data source is behind the ArcGIS GeoEnrichment service?

Tags: arcgis-online, web-service, geoenrichment

I would like to know if there is a reference to the data of the GeoEnrichment service, available with a ArcGIS Online account. I only found [this post](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/82166) of 2013 where it seems there is no reference. Does anyone know anything about it? I would like to know which data I am using. In particular, the data I would like to enrich are from Milan (Italy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean data sets such as [these](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=esri&title=Demographics%20and%20Lifestyle).
It would appear that they use multiple sources and they seem to be credited on the individual pages for each data set/demographic [(eg)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=750242778354424982e7b6a52d25f8d0), the ones that arean't credited I assume are owned by esri. Hope that is what you were looking for.